# Python unicode regex issue

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

Why does this work:

```
>>> ss
u'\U0001f300'
>>> r = re.compile(u"[u'\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF']+", re.UNICODE)
>>> r.search(ss) # this works
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f359acf03d8>
```

But this doesn't:

```
>>> r = re.compile("[u'\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF']+", re.UNICODE)
>>> r.search(ss) # this doesn't
```

Based on Ignacio's answer below, this also works:

```
>>> r = re.compile(u"[\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF]+", re.UNICODE)
>>> r.search(ss)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f359acf03d8>
```

Comment: Those `u'..'` inside the character classes are not doing anything except including `u` as a legal match - along with the apostrophe, twice.

Comment: @MarkReed I don't understand. Based on what you said, how did my very first match succeed (in my post above)?

Comment: Your first match says: "match one or more of any of the codepoints `u`, single apostrophe, and any character from `U+1F300` to `U+1F5FF`".  `ss` contains the single codepoint `U+1F300`, which meets the requirements.

Comment: Character classes are "or"s.   `[ax-z]` matches any of `a`, `x`, `y` *or* `z`.  Your character class matches `u` or `'` or U+1F300 or U+1F301 or ... or U+1F5FE or U+1F5FF.

Comment: @MarkReed Thank you!

Comment: `re.UNICODE` only affects the behavior of `\d`, `\s`, `\w` and has nothing to do with the Unicode/byte semantic of the regex engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `unicode` pattern when performing a search on a `unicode` haystack.

Also, the "u'...'" should not be in the pattern; those are Unicode characters (in the `unicode`) without that regardless.